# how to detect back button of browser in jquery and if any dialogue is open close it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i want to do is, if i press back button when any other pop up is opened , i should close that pop up and reload the page .

i have tried below. but it is only taking the keyboard backbutton but not browser back button. can any one help me to solve this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $(document).bind("keydown keypress", function(e){
            if( e.which == 8 ){ // 8 == backspace
                alert("back button");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Explain your purpose cleary. What your want exactly?

Comment: i need to detect the back button hit of browser as well as in keyboard stroke.,. When i click on backbutton either on browser or keystroke, i need to check weather any dialog box is open..If open , close it and refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

Code snippet for detecting browser back and closing the popup.

```
var path = 'pageURL';
history.pushState(null, null, path + window.location.search);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    //Code to close the pop up
    history.pushState(null, null, path + window.location.search);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stop navigating to this:

```
$(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {

    // if a object has focus
    // inputs, textarea, etc.
    if($(":focus").length != 0) {
        return;
    }

    // else don't allow the press
    if(e.keyCode == 8) {
        parent.postMessage("message");
        window.close();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

For me it captures and disables the browser back. And you can comunicate between windows with [`postMessage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/25098153#25098153)

More info on communicating between windows. https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe